# In Pandas, can't show x-axis dates nicely and y-axis in unwanted logs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here's my chart:

[image]

I have two issues; I can't get the datetime objects on the x-axis to come out nicely (i.e. January 1st, 2013) and I would like the y-axis labels to be absolute values, not log values.

Here's my annotated code: (`date_sorted` is my Pandas dataframe)

```
fig = plt.figure()
date_sorted.plot( x = ["ReleaseDate"], y = ["DomesticTotalGross"])
plt.title("Domestic Total Gross over Time")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.yscale('linear') # ---- this doesn't seem to do anything
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False) #--- this gives this error: AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter.
fig.autofmt_xdate() #thought this was supposed to convert my x-axis datetime objects into nice dates?
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the date format, one way to achieve your objective would be to reset your index to a date format instead of datetime:

```
date_sorted.set_index([ts.date for ts in date_sorted.index]).plot(x="ReleaseDate", y="DomesticTotalGross")
```